# Unable to embed awk/bash commands in python

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

I am trying to subsitute new lines with "\n" to make a single line certficate file. I am using awk and sed to do this, this works fine on a linux machine. But, when I try to embed this code in python its throwing syntax errors.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system("awk '{printf "%s\\n", $0}\' rsacert.pem > test")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    os.system("awk '{printf "%s\\n", $0}\' rsacert.pem > test")
                                                          ^
```

SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: What's the awk command that you're trying to run?

Comment: awk '{printf "%s\\n", $0}\'

Answer (score 0):

The syntax problem begins here:

```
os.system("awk '{printf "%s\\n", $0}\' rsacert.pem > test")
                        ^
```

This is where the python string is terminated and you're inserting line control characters in the python script, rather than the system command

Answer (score 0):

Your command string uses `"` but it also contains `"` so you need to escape those.

```
"awk '{printf \"%s\\n\", $0}\' rsacert.pem > test"
```